# C++: error: ‘class’ has no member named

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism, member

For my graduation thesis I'm programming some finite element code, or to be more precise, I'm modifying an existing program, which is based on 2 class libraries provided by my faculty. As such, I cannot modify these classes, because those are meant to be general.

I have created a class `BurgersMSrc`, which inherits from a parent class `ValSrc`. The child class I have expanded with a method `calcFourierCoefficient`. During compile time I get the following error:

```
burgers1d.cpp:268:12: error: ‘class ValSrc’ has no member named ‘calcFourierCoefficient’
```

This makes sense, since the variable is defined as:

```
ValSrc* srcTerm;
```

which does not have the method defined. Later on the variable is instantiated as either

```
srcTerm = new ConstVS(f);
```

or

```
srcTerm = new BurgersMSrc(prm);
```

where the instantiation is depending on the problem type. Conditionally defining `srcTerm` as either `ConstVS` or `BurgersMSrc` object yields:

```
error: ‘srcTerm’ was not declared in this scope
```

That is not an option either.

So in the end my question is:

> If a variable is defined as a parent class, but instantiated as a child class, how do I access the child's method(s)?

Any help is really appreciated and thanks in advance for your answers.

**Edit**

FYI, I'm not very experienced in C++, yet I do have some programming experience in C# and VBA. I do however like to learn, so pointers towards the right direction are more than welcome :)

**/Edit**

The relevant lines from the header file:

```
#ifndef BurgersMSS_H
#define BurgersMSS_H
#include "mfem.hpp"
#include "mex.h"

class BurgersMSol: public ValSrc
{
   ...
};

class BurgersMSrc: public ValSrc
{

public:

    typedef ValSrc Super;

    BurgersMSrc(ParamDB &prm) {init(prm);}
    virtual void init(ParamDB &prm);

    ~BurgersMSrc(){}

    inline void getValues  (Vector &coords, Vector &msrc){}
    void calcFourierCoefficient(int p){}

private:

    double   nu;
    double   Tn;
    int prob;
    int nTimeSteps;
    int specModes;
    double s_n;
    double tT;
    double deltaT;
    vector <double> a_re;
    vector <double> a_im;
    int accuracy;
    double randomNr;

    double randomNumber(int p){return randomNr;}

};

#endif
```

The relevant lines from the CPP-file:

```
#include "BurgersMSS.h"

void BurgersMSol::init(ParamDB &prm) 
{ 
    ...
}

BurgersMSol::~BurgersMSol(){}

inline void BurgersMSol::getValues (Vector &coords, Vector &msol) 
{
    ...
}

BurgersMSrc::init(ParamDB &prm) 
{ 
    Super::init(); objectName="BurgersMSrc";
    nu = 1.0; prm.find("nu", nu);
    prob = 1; prm.find("problem", prob);
    if (prob == 3)
    {
        ...
        this->calcFourierCoefficient(accuracy);
    }
}

BurgersMSrc::~BurgersMSrc(){}

inline void BurgersMSrc::getValues  (Vector &coords, Vector &msrc)
{
    ...
}

void BurgersMSrc::calcFourierCoefficient(int p)
{   
    for(int n=0;n<specModes;n++)
    {
        if (time == 0)
        {
            a_re[n] = randomNumber(p);
            a_im[n] = randomNumber(p);
        }
        else
        {
            a_re[n] = a_re[n]*exp(-tT) + randomNumber(p);
            a_im[n] = a_im[n]*exp(-tT) + randomNumber(p);
        }
    }
}

double BurgersMSrc::randomNumber(int p)
{
    int mod = pow(10,p);    
    int rN = -mod + rand() % (2*mod);
    randomNr = rN/(double)mod;
    return randomNr;
}
```

The relevant lines from the main program:

```
#include "mfem.hpp"
#include "mex.h"
#include "BurgersMSS.h"
...

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ...

    ValSrc *srcTerm;
    ...

    if (problem==1) {
        ... srcTerm = new ConstVS(f);
        ...
    } else if (problem==2) {
        ... srcTerm  = new ConstVS(f);
        ...
    } else if (problem==3){
        srcTerm = new BurgersMSrc(prm); 
        ...
    } else {
        srcTerm = new BurgersMSrc(prm); 
        ...
    }

    ...
    stiffInt->setSrc(*srcTerm);
    ...

    for (int step = 0; step < nTimeSteps; step ++) {
    ...
        if (problem == 3)
        {
            srcTerm->calcFourierCoefficient(accuracy); //This line throws the error
        }
        ...
    }

    ...
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I'm not very knowledgeable in the area, but look into using a dynamic cast. If you try to dynamic cast the base class to a derived class it should throw an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ValSrc` does not have a method `calcFourierCoefficient`, then you cannot call that method on a pointer to `ValSrc`. You would have to cast to the appropriate type. For example:

```
BurgersMSrc* p = dynamic_cast<BurgersMSrc*>(srcTerm);

if (p)
{
  p->calcFourierCoefficient(accuracy);
} else
{
  // srcTerm was not pointing to an instance of the appropriate type
}
```

Comment: Well, I've interpreted it and after fixing some other errors in the setup of my class-files I got it running on my verification program.

One more question, which is entirely due to my lack of C++ experience and knowledge:

`calculateFourierCoefficient` modifies private members `a_re` and `a_im` of the `BurgersMSrc`-object. If I execute `p->calcFourierCoefficient(accuracy);`, I assume this alters the private members of `srcTerm`, since `p` is defined as a pointer. Is this correct?

Comment: @Eswald No, `BurgersMSrc::calculateFourierTransform` can not see private members of the base class, and even if it could, the similarly named members of `BurgersMSrc` would still take precedence, regardless of how the function is called. A function doesn't know whether it's being dispatched on a pointer, reference, or object, and it wouldn't make any difference if it did.

Comment: @Oktalist, I understand that, thanks, although it still does not entirely answer my question. So let me explain a bit more and see if I understand everything correctly:

I have a `ValSrc` pointer, named `srcTerm`, declared. Later on I instantiate this pointer by pointing to a `new BurgersMSrc()` object, correct? Then at the point I want to manipulate that object, I create a `BurgersMSrc` pointer `p`, which I point to the pointer `srcTerm`. Then I call a function of the pointer `p`. 

Will this function manipulate any members of the `BurgersMSrc` object I originally pointed `srcTerm` too?

Comment: @Eswald You have a pointer to `ValSrc` named `srcTerm`. You instantiate (create an instance of) the class `BurgersMSrc`, and assign `srcTerm` to point to this instance. You create a pointer to `BurgersMSrc` named `p`. You dynamically cast the pointer `srcTerm` into a pointer to `BurgersMSrc` and initialize `p` from the result of this cast. __Both pointers point to the object that you created with `new BurgersMSrc`__; they only differ in their knowledge about its type.

Comment: @Eswald The pointer doesn't "remember" how it was initialized. It doesn't know whether the object it's pointing to came from a `new` or a `dynamic_cast` or anything else. It just assumes that it points at an instance of the class in its declaration (in this case, `BurgersMSrc* p`).

Comment: Dear all, it took a bit longer to confirm this as the answer of my problem. Thanks for all the input, it really helped me understand things in a more fundamental way!

Answer (score 1):

This may be overkill for your problem, but I wanted to present an alternative solution.

In object-oriented programs, having to use `dynamic_cast` or similar techniques to determine an object's type at runtime and then do some type-specific logic is generally considered a symptom of a design problem.  Here is different way to approach it:

```
struct Problem {
    virtual ValSrc &valSrc() = 0;
    virtual void doStep() = 0;

    void main(StiffInt *stiffInt);
};

void Problem::main(StiffInt *stiffInt)
{
    // ...
    stiffInt->setSrc(valSrc());
    // ...

    for (int step = 0; step < nTimeSteps; step ++) {
        // ...

        doStep();

        // ...
    }
    // ...
}

struct Problem1 : Problem {
    ConstVS srcTerm;

    Problem1(F f) : srcTerm(f)
    {
        // ...
    }

    virtual ValSrc &valSrc() { return srcTerm; }

    virtual void doStep()
    {
        // ...
    }
};

struct Problem2 : Problem {
    ConstVS srcTerm;

    Problem2(F f) : srcTerm(f)
    {
        // ...
    }

    virtual ValSrc &valSrc() { return srcTerm; }

    virtual void doStep()
    {
        // ...
    }
};

struct Problem3 : Problem {
    BurgersMSrc srcTerm;

    Problem3(PRM prm) : srcTerm(prm)
    {
        // ...
    }

    virtual ValSrc &valSrc() { return srcTerm; }

    virtual void doStep()
    {
        srcTerm.calcFourierCoefficient(accuracy);
    }
};

struct Problem4 : Problem {
    BurgersMSrc srcTerm;

    Problem4(PRM prm) : srcTerm(prm)
    {
        // ...
    }

    virtual ValSrc &valSrc() { return srcTerm; }

    virtual void doStep()
    {
        // ...
    }
};

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // ...

    if (problem==1) {
        Problem1(f).main(stiffInt);
    } else if (problem==2) {
        Problem2(f).main(stiffInt);
    } else if (problem==3){
        Problem3(prm).main(stiffInt);
    } else {
        Problem4(prm).main(stiffInt);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So if interpret this correctly all code for the main program is included in the struct `Problem`? If so, it does indeed seem a bit like overkill, as it would involve a lot of rewriting, since there are lots of other classes and objects involved. Although I definitely see some advantage in this solution. I'd might discuss it with my professor :).

Comment: @Eswald: There are various ways to organize it.  In your example, this seemed like a good way to structure it since it also eliminated the need to dynamically allocate the ValSrc, but other details of your problem may make some other structure be cleaner.